# Injectors Diameter and Numbers

Tags: propulsion, advanced-propulsion

how would you determine the diameter and the number of injectors if unlike doublets elements are used? The Data given is:

- Isp =286 s
- Chamber pressure= 25 bars
- Propellant pair: Fuel= Hydrazine and oxidizer = Nitrogen Tetroxide.
  density=1004.5 kg/m3 density=1448 kg/m3
- mixture ratio= 1.08 nd
- Thrust = 5KN

Now, from thrust and Isp, I found out the total mass flow rate and then using mixture ratio I found out the fuel and oxidizers mass flow rate. now I assumed velocity from the range 15-30 m/s (30) from del P= 0.5 rhov*v when I find pressure difference across injectors it is not in the desirable range which is 7-15 bars. kindly tell me where i am doing mistake. after that, I can easily find the discharge coefficient from which I can then find the diameter of the orifices. also, please tell me how can we find the number of injectors?
is finding pressure difference across injectors by this method is fine? 0.5*rho*v*v.